# Integral representation of Meijer G function

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, special-functions

How to prove that the integral

$\int_{0}^{\infty} z^a (1+z)^{1-a} e^{-b z^2} dx; \quad a, b>0 $

is given by

$\frac{2^{a-3}}{\pi \Gamma(a-1)} \times G^{3,2}_{2,3}\left(b \middle|
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{1-a}{2},\frac{-a}{2} \\
 -1,\frac{-1}{2},0 \\
\end{array}
\right).$

Comment: It would be helpful if you described what you’ve tried and where you got stuck.